# Using a join model to relate a model to itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

- User
- MentoringRelationship

MentoringRelationship is a join model that has a mentor_id column and a mentee_id column (both of these reference user_ids from the users table).

**How can I specify a relation called 'mentees' on the User class that will return all of the users mentored by this user, using the MentoringRelationships join table?  What relations do we need to declare in the User model and in the MentoringRelationship model?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/30/self-referential-has-many-through, I was able to put something together that works.

**in app/models/user.rb**

```
  has_many :mentee_relationships, :class_name => 'MentoringRelationship', :foreign_key => :mentor_id
  has_many :mentees, :through => :mentee_relationships, :source => :mentee, :foreign_key => :mentor_id

  has_many :mentor_relationships, :class_name => 'MentoringRelationship', :foreign_key => :mentee_id
  has_one :mentor, :through => :mentor_relationships, :source => :mentor, :foreign_key => :mentee_id
```

**in app/models/mentoring_relationship.rb**

```
  belongs_to :mentee, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :mentor, :class_name => "User"
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, referring to the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

```
class User < AR::B
  has_many :mentees, :through => :mentoring_relationship
  has_many :mentors, :through => :mentoring_relationship
end

class MentoringRelationship < AR::B
  belongs_to :mentee, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :mentor, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Untested, but it seems like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using following ways.
In user.rb

```
def mentees
 user = User.find_by_sql("select u.* from the users u, mentoring_relationships m where m.mentor_id = #{self.id} and u.id = m.mentee_id")
end

In controller

@user.mentees >> all of the users mentored by @user
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :mentees, :foreign_key => :mentee_id, 
      :class_name => "MentoringRelationship"

   has_many :mentors, :foreign_key => :mentor_id,
      :class_name => "MentoringRelationship"
end

class MentoringRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :mentee, :class_name => "User"
   belongs_to :mentor, :class_name => "User"   
end
```

With this code you can use

```
@user = User.find(:first)
@user.mentees
@user.mentors
```